# Serializing a XML Document with 3 Levels

Tags: c#, xml, xml-serialization

I am trying to get my output in a specified format for example
**Expected**

```
<?xml version="1.0"?>
<xml>
    <JournalEntries>
      <JournalEntry>
        <Field1>SampleOne</Field1>
        <Field2>SampleTwo</Field2>
      </JournalEntry>
      <JournalEntry>
        <Field1>SampleOne</Field1>
        <Field2>SampleTwo</Field2>
      </JournalEntry>
    </JournalEntries>
</xml>
```

**My Current Output:**

```
<?xml version="1.0"?>
<xml>
  <JournalEntry>
    <Field1>SampleOne</Field1>
    <Field2>SampleTwo</Field2>
  </JournalEntry>
  <JournalEntry>
    <Field1>SampleOne</Field1>
    <Field2>SampleTwo</Field2>
  </JournalEntry>
</xml>
```

So essentially I need to add another `root` ? in a sense so that there is one `JournalEntries` at the start and end. Since a group of entries consists of multiple Entry

```
[XmlRoot(ElementName = "xml")]
    public class JournalDocument
    {
        
        public JournalDocument()
        {
        }

        public JournalDocument(UnProcessedDocument input)
        {
            input.Body.ForEach(o =>
            {
                JournalEntries.Add(new JournalEntry
                {
                    Field1 = "SampleOne"
                    Field2 = "SampleTwo"
                }); ;
            });
        }

        [XmlElement("JournalEntry")]
        public List<JournalEntry> JournalEntries { get; set; } = new List<JournalEntry>();
    }

    public class JournalEntry
    {
        public string Field1 {get;set;}

        public string Field2 {get;set}
    }
```

I don't know if i have my defined root and elements in the correct place and i've tried moving them around but to no luck.. for example i tried putting `[XmlRoot(ElementName = "JournalEntries")]` just above my `JournalEntry` class

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Although IXMLSerializer was an option I ended up creating an extension method instead

```
public static string Serialize<T>(this object obj)
        {
            XmlSerializerNamespaces ns = new XmlSerializerNamespaces();
            ns.Add("", "");
            var xmlWriterSettings = new XmlWriterSettings() { Indent = true };
            XmlSerializer serializer = new XmlSerializer(typeof(T));
            var stringWriter = new StringWriter();
            using var writer = XmlWriter.Create(stringWriter, xmlWriterSettings);
            serializer.Serialize(writer, obj, ns);
            writer.Close();
            return stringWriter.ToString();
        }
```

And my main code I could keep the same with `[XmlRoot(ElementName = "xml")]` but just remove the `[XmlElement("JournalEntry")]`

This ended up solving my issue.

Answer (score 1):

I prefer using `IXmlSerializable`.
It's more flexible to me and gives you much more control over the serialization.

Example:

```
public class JournalDocument : IXmlSerializable
    {
        public XmlSchema GetSchema() => null;
        public void WriteXml(XmlWriter writer)
        {
            writer.WriteStartDocument();
            writer.WriteStartElement("xml");
            writer.WriteStartElement("JournalEntries")
            if(this.JournalEntries.Count != 0)
            {
                foreach(JournalEntrie entrie in this.JournalEntries)
                {
                     writer.WriteStartElement("JournalEntrie");
                     writer.WriteElementString("Field1", entrie.Field1)
                     writer.WriteElementString("Field2", entrie.Field2)
                     writer.WriteEndElement();
                }
            }
            writer.WriteEndElement();
            writer.WriteEndDocument(); // close all open elements
        }
        public void ReadXml(XmlReader reader)
        {
            while(reader.Read())
            {
                if(reader.NodeType == XmlNodeType.element)
                {
                    JournalEntrie entrie;
                    switch(reader.Name)
                    {
                        case "JournalEntrie":
                            entrie = new JournalEntrie();
                            break;
                        case "Field1":
                            entire.Field1 = reader.ReadElementContentAsString();
                            break;

                       // Now make this for every element.
                    }
                }
            }
        }
    }
```